# Adobe PDF JavaScript for Forms: showing & hiding labels depending on the conditions

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe

I am designing forms in PDF and validating user input using JavaScript, however it does not seems to work as planed. Please see my sample code below.

```
var selection1 = this.getField("textfield1").value;
var selection2= this.getField("textfield2").value;

if (selection1 == "Please select" && selection2 == "Please select")
{
    getField("Label1").display=display.hidden;
    getField("Label2").display=display.hidden;
    getField("Label3").display=display.hidden;
}
else if (selection1 == "Please select" && selection2 == "oranges")
{
    getField("Label1").display=display.hidden;
    getField("Label2").display=display.hidden;
    getField("Label3").display=display.hidden;
}
else if ((selection2 == "oranges") && (selection1 == "two" || "four" || "six" || "eight”) )
{
    getField("Label1").display=display.hidden;
    getField("Label2").display=display.visible;
    getField("Label3").display=display.visible;
}
else if ((selection2 == "oranges") && (selection1 == "three" || "five" || "seven" || "nine") )
{
    getField("Label1").display=display.visible;       
    getField("Label2").display=display.hidden;
    getField("Label3").display=display.hidden;
}
```

As you can see from above code, certain labels become hidden and visible depending on the user selection from the multiple drop-down lists.

My 1st issue, in the part of the code `selection1 ==` which has multiple `||` only first condition works i.e. `"two"` and everything else is ignored, if users selects `"four"` for example, nothing happens.

My 2nd issue, when user selects the following combination `selection1 = "Please select" & selection2 = "oranges"` it displays `Label1` for some reason.

My 3rd issue, if for example user selected `selection2 = "oranges" & selection1 = "three"` it displays `Label1` correctly, however if user changes selection to lets say, `selection1 = "two"`, for some reason `Label1` is still visible and `Label2 & Label3` are still hidden.

The above code has been pasted into the Calculation (Printscreen 1) section of the hidden textbox, I have also tried pasting it to Validation section of the drop-down list (Printscreen 2) itself, however nothing seems to be working. I have also tried to use **Switch Statement** but because my `selection1` has multiple conditions it also does not seems to work. Please also note my `selection1` has in the region of 40 `||` conditions, and overall I have in the region of 25-30 different scenarios.

*Your help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.*

Printscreen 1

[image]

Printscreen 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error… In (Acrobat) JavaScript, it is not possible to group various options as it is here (with the logical OR operator (||)).

You'd have to phrase out every decision, such as in

```
… selection1 == "Two" || selection1 == "Four" || selection1 == "Six" || …
```

I guess it is just the sample text here, but if you look at the color coding, there is something wrong with the quotes. In fact, the quote after `"Eight` is a curly quote; JavaScript uses straight quotes. If you simply copied the code into the edit window here, that would be the cause of these problems.

In addition, when I have such a situation (showing/hiding fields based on other selections), I normally hide all of them first, and then show accordingly. This is accomplished easiest by using hierarchical field names (such as `"Label.1"`, `"Label.2"`, `"Label.3"`). In this case, all I have to do to create a known state of visibility is add this line of code:

```
this.getField("Label").display = display.hidden ;
```

and now, I can start showing fields.

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for solving this issue for me, would be perhaps be able to solve my other issue, I have posted another question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634581/adobe-pdf-javascript-for-forms-grouping-conditions-from-if-else-statement)