# Adobe PDF JavaScript for Forms: Grouping conditions from If...else statement

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, adobe

I am designing forms in PDF and validating user input using JavaScript and depending on the user selection different labels appear on the document. Please refer to my sample code below:

```js
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("countryofgrowth").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarquality").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantitymax").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantity").value;
var type = this.getField("type").value;

if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "Afghanistan [AF]" || countryofgrowth == "Albania [AL]" || countryofgrowth == "Algeria [DZ]" || countryofgrowth == "Angola [AO]" || countryofgrowth == "Argentina [AR]" || ……) )
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.visible;
       getField("goodsugar").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
}
else if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == "Australia [AU]" || countryofgrowth == "Belgium [BE]" || countryofgrowth == "Canada [CA]" || countryofgrowth == "Czech Republic [CZ]" || countryofgrowth == "Denmark [DK]" || …..))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;   
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;          

    if (sugarquality == "Low Quality")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
    }
    else if (sugarquality == "High Quality")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;

       if (sugarQualitylevelhigh == " More than 75%")
        {
         getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
        }
        else if (sugarQualitylevelhigh == "Less than 75%")
        {
            getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.visible;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
        }
    }
}
else if ((type == "Corn") && (countryofgrowth == "Aland Islands [AX]" || countryofgrowth == "Alderney" || countryofgrowth == "American Samoa [AS]" || countryofgrowth == "Andorra [AD]" || countryofgrowth == "Anguilla [AI]" || countryofgrowth == "Antarctica [AQ]" || ……))
{
      getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
      getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;  
      getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
      getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
      getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
      getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
      getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;

    if (cornquantity == "More than 500t")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
    }
    else if (cornquantity == "More than 1000t")
    {
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.visible;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;

        if (cornquantitymax == "Yes")
        {
         getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
        }
        else if (cornquantitymax == "No")
        {
            getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarquality").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantity").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.visible;
            getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
            getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.visible;
        }
    }
}
```

My current issue is that each of this `||` - has between 20 to 90 Countries. Currently I have 4 different sets of Countries. My question is there any way to group or declare all this sets of countries within 4 different variables, and then just call single variable when required?

My desired outcome would of been something like this, however I am not entirely sure how to accomplish, *below code does not work, just for illustration purpose to reflect desired outcome*:

```js
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("countryofgrowth").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarquality").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantitymax").value;
var countryofgrowth = this.getField("cornquantity").value;
var type = this.getField("type").value;

var Highriskcountries = ["Afghanistan [AF]", "Albania [AL]", "Algeria [DZ]", "Angola [AO]", "Argentina [AR]", .....];

var Lowriskcountries = ["Australia [AU]", "Belgium [BE]", "Canada [CA]", "Czech Republic [CZ]", "Denmark [DK]", .....];

var Mediumriskcountries = ["Aland Islands [AX]", "Alderney", "American Samoa [AS]", "Andorra [AD]", "Anguilla [AI]", "Antarctica [AQ]", .....];

var Acceptablecountries = ["Aland Islands [AX]", "Alderney", "American Samoa [AS]", "Andorra [AD]", "Anguilla [AI]", "Antarctica [AQ]", "Australia [AU]", "Belgium [BE]", "Canada [CA]", "Czech Republic [CZ]", "Denmark [DK]", .....];

if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == Highriskcountries))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.visible;
       getField("goodsugar").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;
}
else if ((type == "sugar") && (countryofgrowth == Lowriskcountries))
{
       getField("sugarlabel").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarquality").display=display.visible;
       getField("sugarQualitylevellow").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhigh").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighmorethan75").display=display.hidden;
       getField("sugarQualitylevelhighlessthan75").display=display.hidden;   
       getField("cornquantity").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymorethan500").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymax").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxyes").display=display.hidden;
       getField("cornquantitymaxno").display=display.hidden;          
 }
```

Also here is the dropdown fields I am using to ask users initial questions, depending on their answers further dropdown fields will become visible.

[image]

Below are text fields where I currently keep my code, as I already stated in my comments below, all my code currently works fine, however due to the code size limits, each of the text fields can hold, I had to split code between 3 text fields, however I have encountered problem where, I am not able to split some of the deeply nested `if...else` statements, hence I am asking for help to shrink my code, by grouping countries.

[image]

Comment: Is anyone able to help on the below, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this? It may need some adjustments and I haven't tested, but basically you want to create a data structure that will allow you to generically handle every scenarios the same way.

Using objects as maps here rather than arrays to hold countries is just an optimization that would make the country lookup faster, but it's probably not necessary.

```
var fieldKeys = ['sugar', 'corn', 'wheet', 'potatoes'];
var fields = fieldKeys.reduce(function (res, type) {
    res[type] = getField(type + 'label');
    return res;
}, {});

var countriesByType = {
    sugar: {
        'Afghanistan': true,
        'Albania': true
    },
    corn: {
        'Australia': true,
        'Belgium': true
    }
};

updateFieldsVisibility({ type: 'corn', country: 'Albania' });

function updateFieldsVisibility(selection) {
    var countries = countriesByType[selection.type];

    hideOtherTypeFields();

    fields[selection.type].display = display[countries[selection.country]? 'visible' : 'hidden'];

    function hideOtherTypeFields() {
        fieldKeys
            .filter(function (field) {
                return field != selection.type;
            })
            .forEach(function (field) {
                fields[field].display = display.hidden;
            });
    }
}
```

> As you can see for sugar and wheet & corn and potatoes I have the same
>   sequence of countries, so I was hoping to group them somehow to
>   prevent me from repeating them again and again

You could just do the following and use the same approach as above:

```
var sugarAndWheatCountries = {
    'Afghanistan': true,
    'Albania': true,
    ...
};

var cornAndPotatoesCountries = {
    'Australia': true,
    'Belgium': true,
    ...
};

var countriesByType = {
    sugar: sugarAndWheatCountries,
    wheat: sugarAndWheatCountries,
    corn: cornAndPotatoesCountries,
    potatoes: cornAndPotatoesCountries
};
```

To make the code smaller you may create maps dynamically from arrays:

```
var sugarAndWheatCountries = mapFromStringArray(['Afghanistan', 'Albania', ...]);


function mapFromStringArray(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (acc, str) {
        acc[str] = true;
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, unfortunately I am not so advanced in JavaScript (and any other programming language) and please correct me if I am completely wrong and did not understood your code, but I think I would not actually solve my problem. From what I can see in  the following part of the code: `var countriesByType = {
    sugar: {
        'Afghanistan': true,
        'Albania': true
    },
    corn: {
        'Australia': true,
        'Belgium': true
    }`

Comment: I will still need to repeat all the countries for all the scenarios. As you can see for sugar and wheet & corn and potatoes I have the same sequence of countries, so I was hoping to group them somehow to prevent me from repeating them again and again. I was trying to group them together via `array` but I am struggling to understand how to make 4 loops to work for each sequence. Would you please be able to suggest something else?

Comment: Thanks for this again, but what I should off mentiond, sorry my bad, is that I can not group corn, potatoes, wheet and sugar, as they are very individual scenarios with many layers of if and else statements under them, hence I was just lookig for the way to be able to group countries only. Tonigh I can post my 'array' code, maybe you will be able to help me with it, or perhaps you will be able to suggest any other solution, thanks in advance

Comment: Just take the same approach to determine which operation to invoke rather than invoking the generic `updateFieldsVisibility` function. Its not more difficult. You should really properly describe your question next time, as my answer fits your current question.

Comment: Thanks again, unfortenatelly, my Javascript skills are not going that far so I am not sure if I will be able to implement your approach. Really I was just looking for a simple solution, but it seems like there are none. The issue is  that my approach works perfeclty fine, but I started encountering issues when my code got so big it does not fit in the single "Custom calculaion script", so I had to start splitting code between multiple text fields, however as explined each scenario has multiple layers of if ... Else statements which makes it impossible to split between multiple text fields.

Comment: It's always possible to have a good design. Post your entire problem as a queston and I'll try to answer.

Comment: I have edited my original post with extra codes, I have reflect accurate structure of the code and tried to explain my problem to the best of my ability, I have also reflect desired outcome to avoid confusion. Sorry for huge post, was just trying to insert everything as asked. Also thank you for all your help so far, very much appreciated, would be very glad if you could help out with my problem.